# ckeditor bullets open and close double quotes

Tags: ckeditor, quotes, double-quotes

With CKEditor I need to give the user keyboard entry of bullets, left-double-quotes and right-double-quotes.

I already provide the user with numbered and bulletted lists, they want stand-alone bullets.

When I say left-double-quote, I mean “ &#8220 equivalent.
When I say right-double-quote, I mean ” &#8221 equivalent.

The user wants the ability to type these characters directly into a CKEditor textarea.

How should I configure CKEditor to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved this problem during the export to IDML by converting the quotes (""") to their respective ” and “ (&#nnnnn; equivalent) by evaluating the characters next to the quote.

So the user may input ", and I output the desired quote character in it's place.